# how to adjust journal columns

Tags: two-column, thesis, texworks, paper

my paper :

```
    \documentclass[10pt,review,ruled,times,5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\begin{abstract}  
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction \label{sec:Introduction}}
......
```

[image]

how to adjust text on columns and doesn't exceed to margins ?

Comment: the default US english hyphenation patterns would hyphenate representation at any of these places `rep-re-sen-ta-tion` so the output you show is rather surprising but as you have shown no code nor the relevant portion of the output it is really impossible to guess why tex chose that line break

Comment: A note: remove the second `\usepackage{graphicx}`